# Get records from a specific hour every day in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to pull records from SQL Server from a specific hour every day, say at 4 PM.
So if I am running query at 3 PM today, it should pull records from **previous day 4 PM till today 3 PM** (23 hours).
On the other hand, if run query at 4:30 PM today, it should pull query from **today 4 PM to 4:30 PM** (only for half an hour) and so on

How could I do this in plain SQL in  SQL Server?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant table's structure and some sample data, preferably as a DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName <= GETDATE()
AND ColumnName >= 
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 4 THEN 
        DATEADD(HH, 4, CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS date) AS datetime)) 
    ELSE  
        DATEADD(HH, 4, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)) 
    END
```

Points of interest:

1. `CAST(GETDATE() AS date)` will return the date part of the current datetime.
2. Casting back to datetime allows you to use `DateAdd` to get the hour you want
3. using `-1` with date values subtracts a day from the date (`+1` will add a day, of course)
4. using the `CASE...WHEN` allows you to write a single where clause that fits both scenarios described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query, i have created it for stored procedures that had been modified on specific date:

```
Select * from sys.procedures where CONVERT(date,modify_date,101) = 
CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DD,-5, GETDATE()),101)
AND DATEPART(hh,modify_date) >= 1 AND DATEPART(hh,modify_date) <= 22
```

You can pass "**CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DD,-5, GETDATE()),101)**" GEDATE only instead to - minus five days, that was done only to fetch records for me.

and in hours you can specify the range as you want.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Instead of `convert` you can use `cast`: `CAST(GETDATE() As Date)`. Also, you should have done one more step and modify the conditions to fit the requirements.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, thanks.. could you please update the answer if you think it could be better than now. please.. i will also want to see how we could do this. please make  updated in bold and add sql query according to you then we will update the answer accordingly

Comment: Hi Ram, Thanks, I will try your solution a little later.and let you know.

Comment: @RamSingh I've added my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

```
select 1 from table where Col1 between case when hour(getdate())>4 then  convert(datetime,convert(varchar(20),year(getdate()))+'-'+convert(varchar(20),month(getdate()))+'-'+convert(varchar(20),day(getdate()))+' 04:00')  else dateadd(hh,-23,getdate())  end and getdate()
```

Comment: Hi Dhaval, I cannot use Declare etc. due to it is a pass through SQL. Thanks, I will try Ram's solution a little later.

Comment: You can Check My updated Solution which does't use variable @kumaran

Comment: No need to use varchar(20) for a year, char(4) will do better. same goes for month and day (char(2)). Also, adding '04:00' means 4 am, it should be '16:00'. Also, your else clause will return the last 23 hours of data, that's not what the OP is asking for.